# How can the sum of averages of my sample exceeds average of entire population? - market concentration

Tags: mean, percentage, types-of-averages

I want to see what percent of a market of listeners on a livestreaming platform my sample of top 100 musicians with the highest number of average listeners during a given month has. I only have average number of listers active during the month on the platform and each musician's average and peak number of listeners.

Say there were 25,000 active listeners in a given month month, but when I sum all of the average number of listeners each of musician had in my sample it comes out to 140% of the entire platform's average.

How can this be?

I can see the peak number of listeners my sample had and I can also see that the top musician at one point had a peak of 5000 listeners (of the average of 25,000 active listeners on the entire platform), which is a very large amount for one musician. But how can the sum of averages exceed the entire platform average? Or rather, what can I take away from this?

"The these 100 musicians accounted, on average, for the entire market/active listeners on the platform"?

Edit: Perhaps these musicians attract a massive influx of listeners when they're performing which leads to high average listeners every time, the sum of which is higher than the platform average, which is low due to the lower average listener numbers when these sampled musicians don't play?

Edit 2: Knowing that the sum of the average listeners is 140% of the platform's average listeners, would it make sense to infer that these performers attract a large number of new listeners to them and the platform and also account for a substantial and/or disproportionate number of platform listeners on average when they are performing (compared to the next top 101-500)?

I do not know a way to statistically back up any of this information unfortunately besides the '140% of average monthly listeners' part, but eye-balling this gives me this impression. I appreciate any pointers

Comment: It sounds like you assume each listener attends solely to a single performer each month.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I haven't thought of that...Damn. Thank you. This makes things much more difficult I suppose

Comment: Is there only one artist performing at the time, can you listen only to one artist at the time? And are you talking with 25000 about the total number of listeners or the average number of listeners? Do you compute those averages with the same time frame? E.g. at primetime some show might have on average 50000 listeners while the whole station has during the entire day 10000 listeners on average. Obviously the best/most popular artists are attracting on average a higher number of listeners than the whole station.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Theoretically, you could listen to multiple performing artists at the same time. 25000 is the average number of listeners for the entire platform for the entire month. I don't look at smaller time frames within the month, only the entire month and the averages thereof (average listener number per performer and average listener number for the platform). I understand that more popular artists will attract more listeners, and I'm trying to figure out a percentage for this trend, i.e., popular artist X has 10% of the listeners while artist Y only has 0.5%. but then for the top 100

Comment: Would the sum of averages of the top 100 in relation to the average number of listeners tell me anything noteworthy in this regard?

Comment: @eRsms but how do you compute the average number of listeners for an artist? If an artist is only performing from 19:00 to 20:00 and they got 4800 listeners continuously listening during that hour. **1** Do you count this as this artist has an average of 4800 listeners per hour **2** or do you also consider that during the other 23 hours this artist has zero listeners and is actually having an average of 200 listeners over the entire day?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I retrieved the data from a third-party site that collects such data. The smallest interval for data collection is per hour, so I could see the average listener amount from 23:00 to 00:00 for example. Your questions have led me to re-evaluate my approach and I've since gone with a different metric as this was a bit out of my league in terms of statistic knowledge it seems. I was able to get data on 'total listening time' which is an absolute/precise value rather than an average and accounts for people listening to half a performance, listening to it twice and so on. Thank you